# How to complie libxml2 in golang

Tags: go, libxml2

I have a Go application which uses libxml2 library - github.com/lestrrat-go/libxml2.

On running my main.go file. I do not get any issues while on debugging I get:

```
github.com/lestrrat-go/libxml2/clib
In file included from 
    C:/msys64/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:810:0,
   from C:/msys64/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/HTMLparser.h:16,
   from ..\..\github.com\lestrrat-go\libxml2\clib\clib.go:28:
   C:/msys64/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:28:19: fatal 
   error: iconv.h: No such file or directory
   compilation terminated.
   exit status 2
   Process exiting with code: 1
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: You're missing iconv.h, as the error says. A quick Google search for "iconv.h: No such file or directory" will tell you you need to install libiconv.

Comment: Hi, I have  the libiconv downloaded and I read in few posts that we probably need to build it too. But I am using a package which should have precomplied libxml2- github.com/lestrrat-go/libxml2. Also, My go code (the one which uses this library) is running just fine , it is only during debugging I am getting this error. This is very strange to me.